# How to find the value of this integral: $\int_0^n\frac 1x dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I know that the function, $$f(x) = \frac 1x$$tends to infinity when $x$ approaches $0$, but I'm unable to figure out how to calculate this integral - $$\int_0^n\frac 1x dx$$where $n > 0$.

Help.

**Edit:** I wanted to put the limits from $0$ to $n$, but mistakenly I did the opposite initially, my bad. I've reversed it now though. So, answer would be multiplication by $(−1)$ to the answers based on $n$ to $0$ as limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may observe that, for $n>0$,
$$
\int_n^0\frac 1x dx=-\lim_{b \to 0^+}\int_b^n\frac 1x dx=-\lim_{b \to 0^+}[\log x]_b^n=-\log n+\lim_{b \to 0^+}\log x=-\infty.
$$

Comment: What if $n$ is $\infty$?

Comment: @Olivier: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PalashV You are welcome!

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal When one writes $n$ it can't be $\infty$. But one can let $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Then? Do you know improper integrals?

Comment: This one is already an improper integral (due to $0$). Thanks.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal : When $n \to \infty$ the integral goes over to $+\infty$, that is because we must take the limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+, n \to \infty} \log (n/\epsilon) = \log (\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+, n \to \infty} (n/\epsilon)) =  +\infty$